# UNIQUE constraint on table "subscriber_historization" lacks column "processing_date" which is part of the partition key

Tags: postgresql

I want to use constraint so i can use upsert. Because i don't want duplicate entry on customer_identifier_value.

```
on conflict (customer_identifier_value) do nothing

[42P10] ERROR: there is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification
```

When i create the constraint

```
alter table subscriber_historization
add constraint customer_identifier_value_unique unique (customer_identifier_value);

[0A000] ERROR: insufficient columns in UNIQUE constraint definition
Detail: UNIQUE constraint on table "subscriber_historization" lacks column "processing_date" which is part of the partition key.
```

Here is the DDL.

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table subscriber_historization
(
    customer_identifier_value text not null,
    product_value             text,
    contract_date_end         date,
    processing_date           date not null,
    constraint subscriber_historization_pk
        primary key (processing_date, customer_identifier_value)
)
    partition by RANGE (processing_date);
```

If i use

```
ON CONFLICT ON CONSTRAINT subscriber_historization_pk DO NOTHING
```

The row will be inserted if process_date is different. Then there will be duplicate entry on customer_identifier_value.

How to use upsert then?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot prevent that with partitioned tables, because all unique indexes must contain the partitioning key.

Your only way out is to use `SERIALIZABLE` transaction isolation throughout and verify the constraint with a trigger. This will be a performance hit, however.

This is a limitation of partitioning.

Comment: I don't know about this limitation. Many thanks for your answer and solution.